# How to place four Icons side by side in html?

Tags: html, css

I have an icon and I want four of such icon to be placed side by side using minimum css

Here is my HTML code:-

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x" style="margin-left: 32%;margin-top: -13px;">
            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <div style="position: absolute;font-size:1.4vw;margin-left:40%">1</div>                                          
         </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```css
i.fa.fa-square-o.multi-4x:after {
  content:"\f096\f096\f096";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x" style="margin-left: 32%;margin-top: -13px;">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x multi-4x"></i>
  <div style="position: absolute;font-size:1.4vw;margin-left:40%">1</div>    
</span>
```

Comment: Here i have a number inside a div how can it be placed inside those icon like 1 in first , 2 in second , 3 in third and 4 in fourth box.